# Impossible to connect to remote SQL database through VPN & CrossDomain in a web app

Tags: c#, cross-domain, database-connection, connection-string, vpn

I have a web application that needs to connect to databases hosted by a client. A VPN is configured between my company and the client. All ports have been opened. Connection via SQL Server Management Studio works fine. We just need to specify the domain name in the current database (eg `MYSERVER.mydomain`).

In contrast, the connection is not made when a developer tries to run the application in debug mode.

Connection strings are of the type: connectionString = `"Data Source = <SERVERNAME> \ <instance name>; Initial Catalog = <BaseName>; User ID = [login] Password = [password]"`

The connection does not seem to success and the following exception is thrown:

`{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while Establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify que le instance name is correct and SQL Server is configured That to allow remote connections. (Provider : SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance Specified) "}`

We tried the following changes:

- Disable the Firewall Client

- Modify the connectionStrings with: Persist Security Info = True

- Modify the connectionStrings with: Connect Timeout = 120;

Has someone already encountered this problem? At this point, any idea could be great ...

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you connect through management studio is it using sql server logon or integrated. oh and remember to turn your fire wall back on.

Comment: Hi, It's using sql server logon.

Comment: Hmm struggling. Have you tried using IP addresses to take any DNS issues out of the picture? Or just fire up VS and knock up a quick windows app that connects, take the webserver out of the problem.

Comment: Thanks dude! It's probably a dns problem from my client... You rock :D

Comment: Everything might actually be good. If it's recent set up though, it can take awhile for dns names to get propagated. It's irritating us devs shouldn't have to deal with this admin stuff. :)